# Where is option for Java Next-Generation Plugin?

Tags: java, next-generation-plugin

I have a problem starting a commercial JavaWS application on IE11 on some computers at work. The application eventually starts but the user has to try several times before it works whick is very annoying.
We are currently using JRE 1.8.0_40 on Windows 7.
I have tried all possible things and in my research I've seen some references to Java Next-Generation Plugin and that It should be activated. When I open the Java Configuration I can't find this option. Why is that?

[image: No Next-Generation option]

I have been reading this [article](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=340427897) where they mention Next-Generation Plugin and different ways of checking that it's activated.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the article I linked thoroughly you find this way of checking/setting the option in the registry:

1. Go to Start/Run and type in “regedit.exe” in the Run dialog box. Click OK
2. Navigate to the following area in the registry (32-bit Java keys)

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Plug-in\<version>

3. Find or create the registry key UseNewJavaPlugin (REG_DWORD)
4. Ensure this key is set to value 1
5. Close the registry and restart your browser sessions for the setting to take affect