# Java next generation Plug-In setting in Java control panel is not visible

Tags: java

I know it's kind of very basic question but I am unable to find the Java next generation plug in setting in the Java control panel. I tried to find the help in the internet but unable to find any solution for the same. Solution given in the [Where is option for Java Next-Generation Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265096/where-is-option-for-java-next-generation-plugin) is also not working for me.

Someone please help ? My java version is 8 update 51.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to "find the next generation plugin settings in the Java control panel"?

Comment: what settings you want change ? else you could try uninstall/reinstall java in order to get

Comment: I need to run RFT in Mozilla browser in my machine and one of the setting is to enable the Next Generation PlugIn which I am unable to find.

I did reinstall java in my machine but the setting is not there.